# Include Excel Range value in htmlbody of mail

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I'm trying to include Range("F2").Value in .htmlbody.

```
signature = opemail.htmlbody '

With opemail
    .to = "s"
    .Subject = ActiveCell.Value & " - " & "Daily report - " & Date - 1
    .htmlbody = "<p style=""font:11pt Calibri;""> **Range("F2").Value** <br> more text </p>" & signature
```

Cell "F2" have a text which changes with hours (good morning <12,>12 good afternoon).

My English is very basic.

Answer (score 1):

You could use cell reference as stated in your question, you just need to use the **&** symbol to link the strings:

```
.htmlbody = "<p style=""font:11pt Calibri;"">" & Range("F2").Value & "<br> more text </p>"
```

or you could do it within VBA and not use a cell reference:

```
        Dim CurTime
            If Hour(Now) < 12 Then
                    CurTime = "Good Morning"
                Else
                    CurTime = "Good Afternoon"
            End If

        signature = opemail.htmlbody

        With opemail
            .to = "s"
            .Subject = ActiveCell.Value & " - " & "Daily report - " & Date - 1
            .htmlbody = "<p style=""font:11pt Calibri;"">" & CurTime & "<br> more text </p>"
```